# Visual C++ adding WSDL file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wsdl

From my understanding a .wsdl file consists of an xml specification. This abstract way of defining code is then converted into usable code via some means.

I have a C++ program that I am creating in Visual C++ express. I am trying to use a .wsdl file but am unsure about how to proceed. I am presuming that somehow I can add the url of the wsdl and have the code generated automatically.

I've seen similar questions which seem to suggest that there is a way to `add web reference` but I have looked and cannot find this option on Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Comment: I'm not sure what the C++ language is going to do with a WSDL (or any other format) file. You're going to need a parser to allow your code to read and interact with this file. Perhaps something like: http://wsdlpull.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if visual studio provides such an option, having said that I think
You need a library like **[Apache Axis's](http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/)** ***[WSDL2WS tool](http://ws.apache.org/axis/cpp/arch/WSDL2Ws.html)*** which will generate stubs for you by using the wsdl as input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WsUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430644%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to generate client stub in C++ that you can call from your code.