# Add Service Reference in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, web-services

I am working on a C++ tool in Visual Studio 2019. Now I want to use a function from a WebService to get a value.

I have two URLs: one related to the WebService and an other one for WSDL.

How can I call my WL function? I have no option in Visual Studio 2019 to set "Add Service Reference" for my C++ Code.

What do I wrong?

Comment: Right click on "References" in Solution Explorer → "Add service reference" → "Advanced" → "Add Web Reference" → Enter WSDL URL.

Comment: Hi, there is no option called Add service reference. Only Add Reference and Connection Service. And both are not the right one and not working because no Connection Service supported in the current project type.

Comment: Sorry, I read too late that you are developing in C++. My answer was for C#.

Comment: I do think [your question is a duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8814563/107625).

Comment: with WsUtil the URL format is not supported. Or am I using this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [The WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)

Release notes from GitHub [WCF Web Service Reference Provider - Release Notes](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/release-notes/WCF-Web-Service-Reference-notes.md)